# AffineTransform: scaling a Shape from its center

Tags: java, swing, geometry, shapes, affinetransform

I'm trying to scale a rectangle from its center using AffineTransform. I'm sure the solution is obvious but I cannot make it work ! Here is what I've tested so far...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test extends JPanel {
    Test()
        {
        super(null);
        setOpaque(true);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
        }
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g1) {
        super.paintComponent(g1);
        Rectangle r= new Rectangle(5,5,getWidth()-10,getHeight()-10);
        double cx= r.getCenterX();
        double cy= r.getCenterY();
        Graphics2D g=(Graphics2D)g1;
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        AffineTransform old= g.getTransform();
        for(double zoom=0.9; zoom>=0.5; zoom-=0.1)
            {
            AffineTransform tr2= new AffineTransform(old);
            tr2.translate(-cx, -cy);
            tr2.scale(zoom, zoom);
            tr2.translate(cx/zoom,cy/zoom);
            g.setTransform(tr2);
            g.draw(r);
            g.setTransform(old);
            }
        }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new Test());
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't work.... Any suggestion ?

Comment: I assume you're trying to track concentric/internal rectangles?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see what you mean when you're dealing with rectangles. The reason is because the initial calculation for the translation didn't take into account the size of the container object.

Use this instead:

```
tr2.translate(
    (this.getWidth()/2) - (r.getWidth()*(zoom))/2,
    (this.getHeight()/2) - (r.getHeight()*(zoom))/2
);
tr2.scale(zoom,zoom);
g.setTransform(tr2);
```

What this is doing is translating the rectangle to the center of the panel before scaling it. In my tests it works just fine.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming scaling fixes the location of the top lefthand corner of the rectangle (which I think is right but it's been a long time since I've done graphics in Java), you need to translate the rectangle in the direction opposite to the scaling.

```
tr2.translate(
    r.getWidth()*(1-zoom)/2,
    r.getHeight()*(1-zoom)/2
);
tr2.scale(zoom,zoom);
g.setTransform(tr2);
```

So you move the rectangle left and up half of the change in width and height.

Comment: your solution doesn't work but it gives me some new ideas, thanks

Comment: @mmyers: what is the result you get? I don't have access to a Java IDE at work so I can't test it myself. I'm working largely from memory.

Comment: @Welbog: With the original code, all the squares originate in the upper left corner. With your code, they get progressively shifted towards the middle, but not enough.

Comment: Ah, got it. All you have to do is move the scale() after the translate() and it works perfectly.

Comment: Hooops, I'm sorry, I was too fast. This centered square was the most special case. When this is a rectangle anywhere on the screen, your solution doesn't work. I again tried to shift the shape from its center, scake and re-center but I still cannot get the right solution...

Answer (score 1):

I was just working on a desktop application to crop Brittney Spear's face (D.A.Y.) The cropping rectangle had to scale around its center point:

```
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

class ResizableRectangle extends Rectangle {

 ResizableRectangle(double x, double y, double width, double height, Group group) {

  super(x, y, width, height);

  // Set scroll listener for crop selection
  group.addEventHandler(ScrollEvent.SCROLL, event -> {
   double zoomFactor = 1.10;
   double deltaY = event.getDeltaY();
   if (deltaY > 0) {
    zoomFactor = 2.0 - zoomFactor;
   }

   super.setX(getX() + (super.getWidth() * (1 - zoomFactor) / 2)); // Set new X position
   super.setWidth(getWidth() * zoomFactor); // Set new Width

   super.setY(getY() + (super.getHeight() * (1 - zoomFactor) / 2)); // Set new Y position
   super.setHeight(getHeight() * zoomFactor); // Set new Height

   event.consume();
  });
 });
}
```

In general, the algorithm works like this:

- Translate rectangle x-values with: `x + (width * (1 - zoomFactor) / 2)`
- Translate y-values with: `y + (height * (1 - zoomFactor) / 2)`
- Set new width to: `width * zoomFactor`
- Set new height to: `height * zoomFactor`

Answer (score 0):

This involves a process called conjugating a transform.

If S is the scaling you want to do, and T is the transformation that takes point (0,0) to the point that is to be the center of your scaling, then the transform that does the job is

T(S(inverse(T)))

Answer (score 0):

(Later) Here is a solution working without any prior knowledge of the Dimension of the panel.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test extends JPanel
    {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Test()
        {
        super(null);
        setOpaque(true);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,600));
        }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g1) {
        super.paintComponent(g1);
        Shape r= new Ellipse2D.Double(5,380,400,200);
        double cx= r.getBounds2D().getCenterX();
        double cy= r.getBounds2D().getCenterY();
        Graphics2D g=(Graphics2D)g1;
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        AffineTransform old= g.getTransform();
        g.drawLine((int)cx-10, (int)cy, (int)cx+10, (int)cy);
        g.drawLine((int)cx, (int)cy-10, (int)cx, (int)cy+10);
        for(double zoom=1; zoom>=0.1; zoom-=0.1)
                {


                AffineTransform tr2 =AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(-cx, -cy);
                AffineTransform  tr= AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(zoom,zoom);
                tr.concatenate(tr2); tr2=tr;
                tr =AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(cx, cy);
                tr.concatenate(tr2); tr2=tr;

                tr= new AffineTransform(old);
                tr.concatenate(tr2);  tr2=tr;

                g.setTransform(tr2);



                g.draw(r);
                g.setTransform(old);
                }
        }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new Test());
        }
    }
```